# Mission Control to pin different Firefox applications to different desktops

Tags: mac, desktop, mission-control

Using Mission Control I create 2 Desktops. If I create 2 different Firefox launcher files (Firefox1.app and Firefox2.app), I want to pin one Firefox1.app to Desktop-1 and Firefox2.app to Desktop-2. So that when I launch Firefox1.app it opens up in Desktop-1 and Firefox2.app opens up in Desktop-2.

Currently if I pin Firefox2.app to Desktop-2 and then launch Firefox1.app, Firefox1.app directly moves to Desktop-2.

So Mac is able to understand that both these launchers are for the same application.

Instead of directly copy pasting and renaming the Firefox installation folder, I also tried to run Firefox as a different application using Automator as specified by this [link](http://sonnygill.net/mac/mac-multiple-firefox-profiles/).

But this does not work too. Please let me know if this is possible to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They need to be identified by the system as totally different apps. I tried to do it with a completely unrelated app i work closely with the developers of - they told me it would have to be done at compile time. I gave up after that, so I'm going to star this post in case anyone finds an alternative way.

Comment: I tried something like that with Firefox a few weeks ago and after getting the following message I didn't go any farther.  The messages was "_A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time._" and it terminated the second occurrence attempt.  I even renamed the binaries and edited the `Info.plist` file.  I suspect it as Tetsujin mentioned, something would have to be done at compile time to have the binary executable show as other then `firefox` within the binary for the second occurrence to load properly.